# How to get other values from SqlDataAdapter command

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have this code which is used by a login in a Winforms app.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Accs WHERE email = '" + richTextBox1.Text + "' AND password = '" + richTextBox2.Text + "'";

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);

DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dtable);

if (dtable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    // the login operation is successful
    email = richTextBox1.Text;
    pass  = richTextBox2.Text;
}
```

What I want to do is to take the "username" value from the same row.

How can I do that?

This is my accounts table:

[SQL Server account table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtXZI.png)

Comment: Pro tip: set the value of `richTextBox1.Text` to `"' OR 1 = 1; -- yay sql injection"` to log in as the first user in the database. :) Or if you know a specific e-mail address, set it to `"abc@example.com' OR 1 = 1; -- yay sql injection"` to log in as a specific user without a password. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) for more info.

Comment: Oh why did I leave the Or in the second example. Silly me.

Comment: As to your question, look at Rows[0] (the first row)

Comment: damn https://imgur.com/a/KaWz2Z4

Comment: should i make a check for ; or simillar characters then?

Comment: No, you nerd to use parameterized queries (pass your email and password with SQL Parameter and have placeholders in the query.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that you are looking for

```
            if(dtable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                //the login operation is successful
                email = richTextBox1.Text;
                pass  = richTextBox2.Text;
                username = dtable.Rows[0]["username"];
            }
```

Comment: @PiotrRuda happy to help. If my answer solved your problem, then you may accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
String query = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Accs WHERE email = '" + richTextBox1.Text + "' AND password = '" + richTextBox2.Text + "'";
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);

DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dtable);

if (dtable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    // the login operation is successful
    email = richTextBox1.Text;
    pass  = richTextBox2.Text;
}
```

You can select only 1 row by adding `TOP 1` in the start of the query to get only 1 result and yes if you want the username you can get it from

```
if (dtable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   // the login operation is successful
   email = rickTextBox1.Text;
   pass = rickTextBox1.Text;
   username = dtable.Rows[0]["username"];
}
```

Since the image you provided shows that the username column in your database is the first one so you can do it like this as well inside your for loop

```
username = dtable.Rows[0][0];
```

or you can change your query to like this to get only the username

```
String query = "SELECT TOP 1 username FROM Accs WHERE email = '" + richTextBox1.Text + "' AND password = '" + richTextBox2.Text + "'";
```

Instead of getting all the columns you can query for the require column by replacing * in the select command with the column or columns that you are needed for example if you want username and password you can pass this query as well

```
String query = "SELECT TOP 1 username,email FROM Accs WHERE email = '" + richTextBox1.Text + "' AND password = '" + richTextBox2.Text + "'";
```

in the last query you will get 2 columns if the passing arguments are correct and database has record against that entry